# Is the ratio between phase velocity and group velocity a significant quantity?

Tags: waves, phase-velocity

Doing the ratio between phase velocity and group velocity for my specific application in the wavenumber domain I noticed that at a certain wavenumber the graph reaches a peak.
Is the ratio between phase velocity and group velocity a significant quantity?
I did not found anything about this parameter in literature

Answer (score 1):

Group and phase velocities are defined respecively as
$$
v_g=\frac{d\omega}{dk}=\left(\frac{dk}{d\omega}\right)^{-1}
$$
and
$$
v_{ph}=\frac{\omega}{k}.
$$
Whether the ration $v_g/v_{ph}$ has a peak depends on the specific form of the dispersionr elation $\omega(k)$. E.g., in a non-dispersive media, where $\omega=v_{ph}k$ the peak certainly does not appear.